# how to know port number of emulator android?

Tags: android, ajax, restful-url

I have restful web service. An app android client call restful web service by ajax. I don't know IP address and port of emulator android so register a client address access to restful web service. Plz help me.

Code ajax in app android

```
function Get() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://<web service domain>:31132/api/Customer",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

                $('#d').append("success");
            },
            error:function(){
                $('#d').append("Errorrr");
            }
        });
    }
```

code register  client address in restful web service

public static void RegisterCors(HttpConfiguration httpConfig)
        {

```
        WebApiCorsConfiguration corsConfig = new WebApiCorsConfiguration();

        corsConfig.RegisterGlobal(httpConfig);


        corsConfig

          .ForResources("Customer")

          .ForOrigins("?????")// we need to register a client address access to webservice.This is my problem.

          .AllowAll();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell ifconfig tiwlan0
```

tiwlan0 is the name of the wi-fi network interface on the device